# Printing an Ordered List from a JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js file with the following array

```
var fruits = [ "Apples","Oranges","Pears","Grapes","Pineapples","Mangos" ];
```

In my HTML file I want to create a  container and write an ordered list containing all the fruits in the array to the container I just created, however I'm having serious trouble and I can't find much online help. I'm a beginner, this is what I have

```
<div class = "container1">
</div>

<h3>Fruits</h3>
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="Web Programming/Assignments/Assignment #3/assignment3/list.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div container1= "fruits"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: add the javascript your using

Comment: Why do you have items above your `<html>` tags? Where are your closing tags? This is a debugging website, we're not here to do your "Web Programming Assignment #3".

Comment: Its really long piece of code and I only grabbed a snippet

Answer (score 1):

You should give the element an id, your custom html attribute would work as a selector, but the typical way would be the id. Then you can simple create some elements in a loop, giving them the element's text content:

```js
var fruits = [ "Apples","Oranges","Pears","Grapes","Pineapples","Mangos" ];

var el = document.getElementById('fruits');
var ol = document.createElement('ol');
el.appendChild(ol);
fruits.forEach(function (fruit) {
  var f = document.createElement('li');
  f.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fruit));
  ol.appendChild(f);
});
```

```html
<div id="fruits"></div>
```

Just in case you insist on the `container1=...` you can select that with

```
var el = document.querySelector('div[container1="fruits"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly include your script in your html file. At the bottom of the body.

Give your container id of container or as you like.

And code will be something like this:

```
var arrayFruits = ["bananas", "apples", "etc"];

var container = document.getElementById("container"); 

for (var i = 0; i < arrayFruits.length; i++) {
  var list = document.createElement("li");
  list.innerHTML = arrayFruits[i];
  container.appendChild(list);
}
```